# What file allows you to set the default language in Endless Space 2?

Tags: endless-space-2

I know I can change the language by going through steam properties but is there a way to do this in game or by editing a configuration file? If so please let me know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the only way to do this is via right clicking on the game in your steam library-> Properties-> languages.  You might need to restart stem from what some of the posts on the following link say.
https://steamcommunity.com/app/392110/discussions/0/1291816569119420375/

Answer (score 0):

just change it in config.ini in game folder. Default should be Language=english, change it to any other supported by game

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote just change it in config.ini in game folder. Default should be Language=english, change it to any other supported by game
>   Blockquote

File responsible for language is called **"Steam_emu"**